# How to copy and move a database from MySQL to MSSQL and vice versa using Python 3?

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, python-3.x

I'm creating a Python application that could copy and move a database from MySQL to MSSQL and vice versa. I'm done with its GUI and my only problem is the function for Copy and Move. Is there a library or code that I could use in Python 3 to make this possible?

For example:

```
 --------------------
 MySQL    |MSSQL    |
 --------------------
 database1|database4|
 database2|         | 
 database3|         |
 --------------------
```

Copy database1 to MSSQL

```
 --------------------
 MySQL    |MSSQL    |
 --------------------
 database1|database4|
 database2|database1| 
 database3|         |
 --------------------
```

Move database2 to MSSQL

```
 --------------------
 MySQL    |MSSQL    |
 --------------------
 database1|database4|
 database3|database1| 
          |database2|
 --------------------
```

Thank you for helping!

**Update:**

Following the given link of **Sergey**, I'm having error with these codes

```
except ProgrammingError, error: 
    print(error)
```

and

```
raise SystemExit, 1
```

It says that Python 3.4 does not support this syntax

**Found Answer for my update:**

Python 3.*

```
except ProgrammingError as error: 
    print(error)
```

but not sure about this one

```
raise SystemExit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with SQLAlchemy. Basically, the process is as follows:

- reflect the tables in the source database, creating in-memory ORM structures which represent the source database
- use .create_all() to create the tables in the target database. SQLAlchemy takes care of translating idioms of the source database to the destination dialect.
- Read data from the source database and insert it into the destination database.

Here's one script I found by googling for "sqlalchemy puller": https://gist.github.com/thoas/1589496, there are a few others.

**Update:** I'm not sure why you're experiencing the errors you mentioned, but an obvious fix would be to modify the `print_usage` function:

```
def print_usage():
    print """
Usage: -f source_server -t destination_server
    -f, -t = driver://user[:password]@host[:port]/database

Example:-f oracle://someuser:PaSsWd@db1/TSH1 \\
    -t mysql://root@db2:3307/reporting
    """
```

I'd also like to mention that I didn't write that script (although I wrote a few similar ones in the past), so I can not guarantee it to be bug-free or functional. It looks like a decent starting point though.

Comment: The given example on your link is for tables. Well I look into that and thanks for answering. You've given me hope for my project. Hahaha... I'll check if it will work. Thanks! :)

Comment: "copying databases" is a matter of creating an empty target database and then copying tables and data from the source to the target.

Comment: @mushroomgroover: It should be 'raise SystemExit(1)' or 'import sys; sys.exit(1)'

Comment: I'm having error with this one from the link you gave: `def print_usage():
    print """
Usage: %s -f source_server -t destination_server
    -f, -t = driver://user[:password]@host[:port]/database

Example: %s -f oracle://someuser:PaSsWd@db1/TSH1 \\
    -t mysql://root@db2:3307/reporting
    """ % (sys.argv[0], sys.argv[0])`

also i'm using MSSQL I don't know how to call it and its port number unlike MySQL having 3306. my source would be MSSQL.

Comment: I'm having error with that one: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: I've analyzed the codes hours ago and I function it well. It copies the table including its data. My problem on the code from that link is that it only reads a name of a table with only one character like 'a' but if it's string an error occured saying that it can't find the table.